# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException happens in Applet

Tags: java, applet, illegalargumentexception

I have a class as below:

```
public class JSemcorProcessor {

IConcordanceSet semcor;
String[] directories = { "brown1", "brown2", "brownv" };

public JSemcorProcessor() throws MalformedURLException {
    // construct the URL to the Semcor directory
    String path = "./files/semcor3.0/";
    URL url = new URL("file", null, path);

    // construct the semcor object and open it
    semcor = new Semcor(url);
    semcor.open();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {

    JSemcorProcessor jsp = new JSemcorProcessor();
    SynsetGraph graph = jsp.startOne("br-a06");

}
.......
}
```

It works well when I call main().
But now I want to use this class in an Applet:

```
public void init() {

    JSemcorProcessor jsp = null;
    SynsetGraph graph = null;
    try {
        jsp = new JSemcorProcessor();
        graph = jsp.startOne("br-a06");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    } 
........
}
```

Such exception occurs:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at edu.mit.jsemcor.main.Semcor.<init>(Semcor.java:105)
    at edu.mit.jsemcor.main.Semcor.<init>(Semcor.java:90)
    at edu.mit.jsemcor.main.Semcor.<init>(Semcor.java:77)
    // semcor = new Semcor(url);
    at edu.njit.tagging.JSemcorProcessor.<init>(JSemcorProcessor.java:40)
    // jsp = new JSemcorProcessor();
    at org.jgrapht.demo.JGraphAdapterDemo.init(JGraphAdapterDemo.java:157)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Why the same code which works in main() does not work in Applet? It seems that URL object invoke this problem in Semcor.

Thanks.

Comment: Running the code in the Applet is not the same as running it locally on your machine. Post the source code of Semcor.java so we can provide you more guidance

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).